# Can't configure model resource on config.xml

Tags: magento

I get a fatal error when trying to instantiate a Model in Magento and call method load().
I've just config the resource model and maybe my config.xml is not well-formed.

```
<config>
<frontend>
<routers>
    <weblog>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Mypack_Weblog</module>
            <frontName>weblog</frontName>
        </args>
    </weblog>
</routers>
</frontend>   
<global>
<models>
    <weblog>
        <class>Mypack_Weblog_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
        <weblog_mysql4>
            <class>Mypack_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>              
        </weblog_mysql4>
    </weblog>   
</models>
</global>
</config>
```

I'm a beginner and spent many hours on it : please, help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resource model doesn't go inside the other model.

```
<global>
    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>Mypack_Weblog_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </weblog>   

        <weblog_mysql4>
            <class>Mypack_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>              
        </weblog_mysql4>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: "Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php on line 225"

Comment: Where do you describe the database table for whichever entity you are loading? Have you created a table? Have you considered using [ModuleCreator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1108/modulecreator/) to do this sort of boilerplate for you?

Comment: The table exists, but not describes yet. According the tuto, it should work anyway at this point (no r/w)

Comment: What is the PHP that triggers the error? Is it a call to `load()`?

Comment: I would use xdebug and see if you can identify what _resourceName is being set as. then work from there. LOVE xdebug :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm working through the same tutorial (http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm) and have figured out the way that config.xml should look at the point in the tutorial where you seem to be:

```
<config>    
<modules>
    <Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <weblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog</module>
                <frontName>weblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
    <!-- ... -->
    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model</class>
            <!-- 
            need to create our own resource, can't just
            use core_mysql4
            -->
            <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </weblog>
        <weblog_mysql4>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>
        </weblog_mysql4>
    </models>
    <!-- ... -->
</global>
```

Excuse the less-than-pretty indentation :).

Comment: Thanks ! I've  took a step back and saw i'd made a mistake in a folder's name ! Mysqll4 instead of Mysql4 ... arghhh ! Have a good day